# Arithmetic statements in bash if clause

Tags: bash, shell, math

Just a quick question about the above stated topic:

I'm currently trying to use a value i am given through read in my if statement:

```
if [ $value1 -lt $value2 -a $value1 is -ge $value2/2 ]
```

How is it possible to compare one value to half of another without having to make an equation beforehand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Bash arithmetic:

```
if (( value1<value2 && value1>=value2/2 )); then
```

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX version (which also works in `bash`, although clumsier than using an arithmetic statement) is

```
if [ "$value1" -lt "$value2" ] && [ "$value1" -ge $(( "$value2" / 2)) ]
```

(As an aside, don't use `-a` for logical AND; it's an extension to the POSIX standard that isn't guaranteed to be implemented by all compliant shells.)